# How to apply a function to the elements of a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, lambda, dataframe

I want to apply a lambda function to the elements of a dataframe, in the same way as np.sqrt returns a dataframe with the sqrt of each element. However pd.DataFrame.apply apply the function to an row or an column. Is there a similar comand that apply a lambda function on each element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions) method:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( { "a": [1,1], "b":[1,2], "c":[3,5]})
df
     a  b  c
  0  1  1  3
  1  1  2  5
 [2 rows x 3 columns]

f = lambda x: x+2

df.applymap(f)
     a  b  c
  0  3  3  5
  1  3  4  7
  [2 rows x 3 columns]
```